# Can a Python package create a variable that is persistent through multiple instances of itself?

Tags: python, package

Say I have a package that gets input from a number of files.

In my script I might do this:

```py
# script_1.py
import my_package
my_package.add_project('MyProject', '../file.txt')
```

Then, within `my_package`, `MyProject` is added to an internal list of projects and the location of the given file is also saved.

So in another script, possibly at a completely different time but still **in the same python environment**, I should be able to do this:

```py
# script_2.py
import my_package
proj = my_package.get_project('MyProject')
```

Is it possible for a python package to manage a global, persistent variable like that?

Comment: Why not write the data to a file?

Comment: @PM2Ring Is there a safe place per-environment for me to do that?

Comment: You could write the file to the same directory that the script's in. You can get the script's path from `__file__` . There's a little bit of info about that on https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I can think at least 2 ways to achieve this:

**1) GLOBAL VARIABLES**

*my_package.py*

```
from pathlib import Path

PROJECTS = {}


def add_project(name, path):
    PROJECTS[name] = Path(path).read_text()


def get_project(name):
    return PROJECTS[name]
```

*main.py*

```
import script1
from script2 import proj

print(proj)
```

**2) OOP APPROACH**

*script1.py*

```
# script_1.py
from my_package import ProjectManager
ProjectManager.add_project('MyProject', '../file.txt')
```

*script2.py*

```
# script_2.py
from my_package import ProjectManager
proj = ProjectManager.get_project('MyProject')
```

*my_package.py*

```
from pathlib import Path


class ProjectManagerSingleton:

    def __init__(self):
        self._projects = {}

    def add_project(self, name, path):
        self._projects[name] = Path(path).read_text()

    def get_project(self, name):
        return self._projects[name]


ProjectManager = ProjectManagerSingleton()
```

*main.py*

```
import script1
from script2 import proj

print(proj)
```

With both of them you'd guarantee uniqueness in the same python process

Comment: How does this persist the data across different invocations of the script?

Comment: @PM2Ring Read the last line of my answer. Question says `So in another script, possibly at a completely different time but still in the same python environment`, I understood the same python environment OP meant the same python process... it depends how you interpret it

Comment: By python environment I meant the install environment eg a virtualenv or a system-wide install

Comment: I see, it seems I haven't understood your meaning then afterall. Well, it'd be trivial to modify my answer to achieve what you want actually, instead keeping the paths content in memory, just make sure to keep path references and then just make sure to dump/persist to disk using the path methods. For more info, check [https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)